# Which football club started the tradition of announcing player's name 3 times when they score a goal?

Tags: football, trivia, history

As you have probably seen that many teams(Bayern Munchen, Napoli) have the player's name announced 3 times by the announcer, when they score a goal.
I want to know where/when this tradition started.

Comment: I disagree with the close flag, it's a valid (trivia) question and rather clear in formulation.

Comment: I don't think there's a definitive answer - I remember watching Grimsby Town in the late 70's and the guy on the p.a. used all sorts of verbal celebrations, and I've got NO DOUBT that included multiple screeches of the home scorers name - in the playground we'd replicate this, I'm sure this tradition went way back, picked up from more flamboyant nations (think S.America)